Does adverse selection affect roll seller more than buyer?
This paper that analyzes the determinants of dollar roll specialness seems to make the underlying assumption that adverse selection related to CTD pools affects the roll-seller more than the roll buyer. They justify it by saying the below:
We expect this risk to be limited because (1) the roll buyer has the last say on the
delivered CUSIP, and (2) the roll trade date is usually close to the front-month settlement date when both counterparties have a good idea on the cheapest MBS in practice.
But, both of the above points don't seem like strong evidence to believe that the roll seller suffers more from adverse selection (i.e. the roll trade does not necessarily need to be close to the front-month settle date and having last say won't necessarily stop pools with unfavorable characteristics from being delivered to the buyer)
As such, would like to understand if there is further justification for believing the roll seller should be more affected by adverse selection than the buyer? Or is this more of a simplifying assumption for the purposes of a research paper, rather than anything truly practical?

Adverse selection is when one party knows something the other does not and is able to "cheat them" as a result. So it is always asymmetric, reflecting an information asymmetry.

@nbbo2 Thanks. As such, I would like to understand what the information asymmetry is in the case of a dollar roll. My rationalization is that there is less information about pools that would likely be delivered in the back month compared to the front month and that could be the information asymmetry, but at any point the buyer and seller should have the same information. Is this what you were referring to?
